# HttpCookie set to different domain

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, cross-domain

I am trying to add a cookie to another domain using HttpCookie. Let's say I have an application which domain is abc.com, I want to set a cookie to a different domain, bcd.com. I have tried using the following code, but it won't set the domain.

```
HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie")
        {
            Path = "/",
            Value = "my vallue",
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = false,
            Domain = ".bcd.com",
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2) 
        };
```

Is it possible to set a cross domain cookie? If not, why .Net provides the Domain property with a public setter?

Thanks,

Comment: you can set in code and try to send it back but the browser will not take it

Answer (score 1):

You can not. Browser prevents you from doing that for obvious security reasons. The setter is public because you may want to set it to wildcard, for example: *.abc.com